# Перенаправят пользователя на другую страницу при ошибке. Единая точка обработки ошибок

Tags: php, php7

Я хочу, создать 2 режима работы сайта: продакшн и девелопер. Если включена продакшн версия, то при некритических ошибках (ошибках, которые были обработаны) пользователю просто должно выводится сообщение что-то не так, а сама ошибка записываться в логи. Если ошибка критическая (например нет скобки или переменная не была определен), то нужно перенаправлять пользователя на страницу 500 ошибки. В режиме разработчика оставляем все как есть. 
Это делается стандартными try catch или как-то еще?

**UPD 1:**

```
try{
    $d = 'wrf'be
}catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Errrrrr';
}
```

В данном случаи try catch не работает 
[image: img]
В таком случаи, надо перенаправить пользователя на 500.

Comment: В режиме разработчика оставляем все как есть. - Это как?

Comment: @Anamnian это значит, что надо оставлять стандартную обработку ошибок и выводить все.

Comment: @SanychGoilo я дополнил ответ про `try-catch`, про режим разработчика это, к сожалению, другой вопрос, который требует другой(новой) темы для дискуссии и советов. Либо додумаете сами :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try ... catch` везде не напишешь... Но в некоторых моментах без него не обойтись.

ОДНАКО, есть хорошая практика по использованию:

[set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php) — Задает пользовательский обработчик ошибок

[set_exception_handler()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-exception-handler.php) — Задает пользовательский обработчик исключений

[register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php) — Регистрирует функцию, которая выполнится при завершении работы скрипта

Советую рассмотреть их как вариант для решения Вашей задачи. Они позволяют перехватывать ошибки и следовательно вы сможете производить необходимые манипуляции.

---

Конкретно про ваш `ParseError`, и разъясню немного:

`try-catch` ловит только те ошибки, которые вы укажите.

[Полный список посмотреть тут.](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.exceptions.php)

Однако-ж в Вашем конкретно случае не получится обработать ошибку. Если доступными словами: У нас есть основной парсер, который когда видит: `$d = 'wrf'be` - он тут уже запинается, и не может найти завершение(тобишь наш `catch`), потому что видит не просто `$d = 'wrf'be` а идет дальше: `$d = 'wrf'be}catch (Exception $e){echo 'Errrrrr';` - собсна как-то так. Для него нет такого: *мол увидишь `}catch()` - стопуй, для него это все одна неправильная строка*.

НО вы можете сделать по другому:

```
try{
    require 'file_with_syntax_error.php';
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo 'test';
}
```

А в `file_with_syntax_error.php`:

```
<?php
$d = 'wrf'be;
```

Вот теперь основной парсер знает где и что, поэтому такой пример будет работать.

Теперь пару слов об ошибках:

`Throwable` - ловит все поддерживаемые виды ошибок.

`ParseError` - как раз что вам нужно, это именно та ошибка которая в вашем случае выбивается.

Сразу покажу на примере:

```
try{
    require 'file_with_syntax_error.php';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '1';
} catch (ParseError $e) {
    echo '2';
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo '3';
}
```

В данном примере ответ будет: `2`.

Объяснение: У нас ошибка синтаксиса, поэтому `Exception` не подходит, он пропускается, идем дальше видим `ParseError` - это и есть синтаксические ошибки включительно, поэтому тут и остановится. Если бы отсутствовал этот `catch`, то ответ был-бы `3`, потому что как я уже говорил `Throwable` - ловит все что только можно (*как Акинфеев в серии пенальти против Испании*). Если отсутствует и `Throwable` то `try-catch` не сработает, и вы увидите ошибку на экране, работа скрипта будет остановлена.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из вашего описания, у все имеется два вида обрабатываемых исключений: **некритические ошибки**, для которых тогда надо определить custom Exception и в блоке catch писать в лог, и **критические** - как результат редирект. Также явно еще будет третий вид **неучтенных** исключений

```
try{
      <...>
}
catch(NonCriticalExp e){
     <пишем лог>
}
catch(CriticalExp e){
     <редирект>
}
catch(Exception e){
     <иные действия>
}
```

По моему мнению, try/catch оптимальное решение

Comment: Ty catch не обрабатывает описки.